# Using the same userscript to run different code at different URL's

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I know it is possible to run a script on different URL's by adding `@include` statements, but it is possible to run different sets of code based on the URL?

My script currently works properly but I had to break it into 5 separate userscripts and it feels kind of sloppy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To switch what code runs, per URL, use `if()` or `switch()` statements against parts of [the location object<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

To avoid false positives and side effects, it is best to just test that property that is most discriminating (usually `hostname` and/or `pathname`).

For example, **for a script running on different *sites***:

```
if (/alice\.com/.test (location.hostname) ) {
    // Run code for alice.com
}
else if (/bob\.com/.test (location.hostname) ) {
    // Run code for bob.com
}
else {
    // Run fall-back code, if any
}

// Run code for all sites here.
```

Or, **for same-site, different *pages***:

```
if (/\/comment\/edit/.test (location.pathname) ) {
    // Run code for edit pages
}
else if (/\/comment\/delete/.test (location.pathname) ) {
    // Run code for delete pages
}
else {
    // Run fall-back code, if any
}

// Run code for all pages here.
```

Note the use of escape `\`.
`.test()` is used for the awesome power of regex.  For example,
`/(alice|bob)\.com/.test (location.hostname)`.